# methods of research / methods from research / researching methods

Tags: american-english

Are the two the same? I feel as if, **method of research** could also be **method from research**? But all in all, Wouldn't *of* and *from* still have the same kind of meaning? If so, then would it make sense to also compare to **researching methods**?

For an example,

"Scientists should use alternative methods of research on mice labs"

"Scientists should use alternative methods from research on mice labs"

"Scientists should use alternative researching methods on mice labs"

Do these 3 examples give the same end result of context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the prepositions "of" and "from" have meanings and usages that are fairly distinct.

(1) "From" generally refers to a starting point or a source of something.  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from

(2) "Of" generally refers to a relationship or connection between two things -- a part of a whole, a possession, etc.  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of

So the phrase "methods of research" would mean "the methods scientists use to accomplish research."  In contrast, the phrase "methods from research" would mean "the methods that scientists discovered as a result of research."  The meanings are very different.

For the last example, the correct grammar would be "...alternative *research* methods..."  Using the noun "research" as a modifier for "methods" conveys the same idea as "...methods of research...".

I know that other languages have prepositions that can be used in either sense -- the French "de" for example, depending on how it's used, may translate as either "of" or "from" in English.  This might be what's confusing you(?)

One other note:  the prepositional phrase at the end of all three examples has two errors.  Instead of "on mice labs" it should be "in mouse labs."

- Using "on" makes it sound as if the scientists are studying the labs themselves, rather than using the labs to study some other scientific question.
- When using a noun as a modifier in English, the singular is normally used instead of the plural.  For example a farm that raises pigs is a "pig farm," not a "pigs farm."